# pandas to spark dataframe

Tags: pandas, pyspark, databricks

I am trying to create two spark dataframes using two pandas dataframes.
1st pandas dataframe has 2 or more than 2 same columns from 2nd dataframe so how can I create two spark dataframes in single spark session without getting name already used as a name or title error and without changing the column names.

pandas data frames df_cbm and df_sku
I am able to create df_cbm to spark dataframe but while creating the spark dataframe for df_sku  I am encountering the name already used as a name or title error because of those two pandas dataframe have 2 or more than 2 similar columns.

Comment: Can you provide a full reproducible example please?

Comment: Please provide the given input and the expected output as an example.

Comment: Welcome to SO. For better chances of receiving answers, please check out [ask] and [mre].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The below code works for me. Please share your example if it still doesnt work.

```
df_cbm =pd.DataFrame({"Name":["Jim","Matt","Harvey","Jared","Ben","Ashley","April","Kate","Kiara"],
                 "Grade":["A","A","A","A","B","B","C","C","C"],
                 "Score":[1,2,3,None,4,5,6,None,8]
                })
df_sku=df_cbm[["Name","Grade"]].copy(deep=True)
df_cbm=spark.createDataFrame(df_cbm)
df_sku=spark.createDataFrame(df_sku)
df_cbm.show()
df_sku.show(
```